# BinaryNode and oldNode was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, struct, scope

In my .h file I have:

```
class BST
{
private:
    struct BinaryNode
    {
        //variables

    };

    ...

public:

    ...

}
```

When I try to use my struct `BinaryNode` such as in my .cpp file:

```
int BST::height(BinaryNode *t)
{
    ...
}
```

I get the error that `BinaryNode was not declared in this scope`

In another function in my .cpp I have:

```
int BST::remove(const DataType &x, BinaryNode *&t)
{
    ...

    else
    {
        BinaryNode *oldNode = t;
        delete oldNode;
    }
}
```

Which gives me the error on `BinaryNode *oldNode = t` that oldNode was not declared in this scope. I have tried declaring it in the beginning of my function as `BinaryNode *oldNode;` but that too doesn't work. I was under the impression that what I did now is also called declaring it and because it is within the same function it has been declared in that scope.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BinaryNode is contained in the namespace of the enclosing class.  Do this:

```
int BST::height(BST::BinaryNode *t)
```

You can also try this:

```
using  BST::BinaryNode
```

at the top of the CPP file, though I'm not sure the universality of support for "using".

Comment: The `BST::BinaryNode` worked, but if I were to have a function that returns BinaryNode, would I have to use `BST::BinaryNode function(BST::BinaryNode);`

Comment: Yes, you would need to use it on the return type as well.